# RedisStore session still alive though browser closed

Tags: node.js, redis, express-session

I am expecting session will be removed when a browser closes, but the session is still alive though the browser closes.

Here is my code.
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b60v9.png)

Below is screenshot of redis-cli before and after closing the browser.
[before and after closing the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwtRR.png)
this shows the session is not removed..

Please any guide.
Thanks

I have tried several times with changing parameters maxAge and checkPeriod , but not worked.

Comment: Solved it by changing the option 'saveUninitialized' to false.

Comment: Please don't use images, add the code directly to your text.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration `saveUninitialized` is set to `true` in your code. According to the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html#saveuninitialized), this results in the session not being removed.

Set `saveUninitialized` to `false` to achieve the session to be removed in your use-case.